Google Recaptcha Cloud backend incomplete?
I've used Google Recapctha many times, but this last time I set it up, it is the first time I have come across this issue. I am setting it up with a plugin, which has the option of enabling Google Recaptcha and just asks for the keys.
I got an email from Google stating there was an issue or something, so I deleted that key and created another, but I still see this:

I go to the Integration tab, and see this:

This is relevant to me, and I am using the key you get when you click the respective link, which is the legacy key.
So, why am I still seeing this message? Do I need to do anything or will it fix itself?
